# retrieving values from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and I have to get the data from multiple tables with common id, but the problem is that in few tables that common id contains multiple records,using inner join gives me separate rows of data e.g.

```
{"dish_id":"52","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","extraId":"2"}
    {"dish_id":"52","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","extraId":"3"}
```

extraId is the multiple record for the dish_id:52.
I need result like this.

```
{"dish_id":"52","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","extraId"[{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"]}}
```

My query is:

```
 $orders =  "Select DISTINCT order_detail.dish_id,order_detail.quantity,order_detail.STATUS,
order_main.franchise_id,order_main.order_type,
order_extras.extra_id,order_extras.extra_title,
order_addons.addon_id,order_addons.addon_size 
from order_main 
INNER JOIN order_detail ON order_main.id=order_detail.order_id 
INNER JOIN order_extras ON order_main.id=order_extras.order_id 
INNER JOIN order_addons ON order_main.id=order_addons.order_id 
WHERE order_main.franchise_id='$storeId' 
and 
order_detail.STATUS!='$order_status'";
```

please help.

Comment: Try group by on id fields.

Comment: would you pls help me with the group as am quiet new to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `group_concat`.  Something like this:

```
Select d.dish_id, d.quantity, d.STATUS, m.franchise_id, m.order_type,
       group_concat(e.extra_id) as extraids
from order_main m INNER JOIN
     order_detail d
     ON m.id = d.order_id INNER JOIN
     order_extras e
     ON m.id = e.order_id INNER JOIN
     order_addons a
     ON m.id = a.order_id 
where m.franchise_id = '$storeId' and d.STATUS <> '$order_status'
group by d.dish_id, d.quantity, d.STATUS, m.franchise_id, m.order_type;
```

Your desired results do not include these columns:

- `e.extra_title`
- `a.addon_id`
- `a.addon_size`

I would also suggest that you remove the join to `order_addons`.

Notice that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: The result is this :
[{"dish_id":"32","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","group_concat(e.extra_id)":"2,1,2,1"},{"dish_id":"52","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","group_concat(e.extra_id)":"2,2"}]

Comment: if there is any other better way of doing it pls guide me to it.

Comment: the extra id for dish_id 52 is only one which is "2" and for dish_id 32 the extra ids are 1,2 but the result is not correct:
[{"dish_id":"32","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","extraids":"2,1,2,1"},{"dish_id":"52","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","extraids":"2,2"}]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by`with `dish_id`

```
$orders =  "Select DISTINCT order_detail.dish_id,order_detail.quantity,order_detail.STATUS,
order_main.franchise_id,order_main.order_type,
order_extras.extra_id,order_extras.extra_title,
order_addons.addon_id,order_addons.addon_size 
from order_main 
INNER JOIN order_detail ON order_main.id=order_detail.order_id 
INNER JOIN order_extras ON order_main.id=order_extras.order_id 
INNER JOIN order_addons ON order_main.id=order_addons.order_id 
WHERE order_main.franchise_id='$storeId' 
 and 
order_detail.STATUS!='$order_status' group by order_detail.dish_id";
```

Comment: [{"dish_id":"52","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","extra_id":"2","extra_title":"extra cheese","addon_id":"1","addon_size":"small"},{"dish_id":"32","quantity":"1","STATUS":"pending","franchise_id":"5","order_type":"PickUp","extra_id":"1","extra_title":"spicy","addon_id":"1","addon_size":"small"}]

Comment: This is the result now its not adding multiple record in each row its just adding one of the record from that table, because there are two extras and to addons with this dish_id:52 in that particular table.